# Control of type I error rate in functional ANOVA F-test

Tags: anova, permutation-test, f-test, type-i-and-ii-errors, functional-data-analysis

I am following how to compare curves via functional data analysis, specifically functional ANOVA. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSGLFpmF6jE&list=PLOdMinGElTQenPYWhochrqgAa4M3wXdEP&index=18&t=0s) makes sense in describing it as being a lot like vanilla ANOVA...up to a point. When we do permutation F-tests for pointwise comparisons at every input value of the function (all 365 of them in the video), is there no need to control for multiple testing? The pointwise testing seems like it goes along the input values and says, "Okay, no significant difference at $x=1$...ah, significant difference at $x=2$, another significant difference at $x=3$...no significant difference at $x=4$."

This reminds me of the [classic XKCD cartoon about jelly beans](https://xkcd.com/882/). We're looking for differences until we find some, which exposes us to a considerable type I error rate, certainly higher than where we've set $\alpha$.

The pointwise hypotheses are not independent, so a method like Bonferroni, conservative as it usually is, seems like it would be absurdly conservative and absolutely sap away our power to reject in all but the most obvious situations. However, there are other methods for controlling type I error rate that might give a more acceptable tradeoff between type I and type II error rates.

Do people just not care about the risk of type I errors in this form of testing? Why is this method of pointwise comparisons in the permutation F-test not akin to looking at jelly beans until we find that the green ones cause acne?